# Javascript Regexp: match string beginning with X, excluding Y, ending with A or B

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match single line strings that start with `./`, do not contain `main` and do end in `.js` or `.vue`

Should match:

```
./test.js
./component.vue
```

Should not match:

```
./main.js
./data.json
```

I tried using a lookahead like this:

```
/^\.\/(?!main)(\.js|\.vue)$/
```

but that doesn't return any of the above strings.

Comment: You're almost there, you just need to match the string between `./` and `.js` or `.vue`. Try `^\.\/(?!.*?main).*?(\.js|\.vue)$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
^\.\/(?!.*main).*\.(?:js|vue)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HoxuSL/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `\.\/`: Match `./` at start
- `(?!.*main)`: Negative lookahead to assert we don't have `main` anywhere
- `.*\.(?:js|vue)`: Match any string that ends with `.js` or `.vue`
- `$`: End